# Converting UTC time (HH:MM) to local time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For example, if the output of the api is "13:29" and mountain daylight time is -6 UTC, how would I go about subtracting 6 from the 13 hour mark? I already have the local UTC time difference worked out below.

```
const date = new Date();
let timeDifference = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the local time by setting the UTC hours/minutes of a new date.

```js
const utcTimeToLocalTime = (utcTime, hour12 = false) => {
  const [hour, minute] = utcTime.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v, 10));
  
  const now = new Date();
  now.setUTCHours(hour);
  now.setUTCMinutes(minute);

  return now.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12
  });
};

console.log(utcTimeToLocalTime('13:29'));       // 09:29    (EDT) or 06:29    (PDT)
console.log(utcTimeToLocalTime('13:29', true)); // 09:29 AM (EDT) or 06:29 AM (PDT)
```